# Is it possible to automatically change slides with a frame with [allowframebreaks]

Tags: beamer, animations, transition

I have a list of references in a frame with [allowframebreaks]. It results in a total of 19 more slides with my references.

Is it possible to use the \transduration{} command so beamer will change my references slides (with frame breaks) automatically?

I tried the following, but only the first slide is changed:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\transduration{1}   
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to specify the `\transduration` inside of the `\frametitle` because the title is used on each slide.
However, I am not sure whether that is the most elegant solution.

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References\transduration{1}}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{frame}
```